# MongoDB how to reference object's properties in query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am attempting to run a script on my MongoDB which will set `teacher_ids[] = [document.owner_id]`. `owner_id` already exists on all of the objects in the collection. My current attempt looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('readings').update({ $where: "this.teacher_ids[0] != this.owner_id" }, { $set: { "teacher_ids": [this.owner_id] }}, { multi: true })
```

Everything *almost* works, except that the document looks like

```
doc: {
    owner_id: "some_id",
    teacher_ids: [undefined]
}
```

which must mean that `this` in the second argument of `update` is not referencing the document. How do I get it to set:

```
teacher_ids = [document.owner_id]
```

Example Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586f07bd6a2169fdffb0563b"),
    "teacher_ids" : [],
    "owner_id" : "57c268dd6c9fd2320035e67e",
    "source" : "http://www.omfgdogs.com",
    "title" : "Test",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-01-28T07:43:46.597Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-06T02:58:05.699Z")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think in update component you can reference any other field value by this or otherwise.

It can be done through script though

```
db.getCollection('readings').find({ $where: "this.teacher_ids[0] != this.owner_id" }).forEach(function(x){x.teacher_ids = [x.owner_id]; db.readings.save(x)});
```

Comment: I ran this query on a sandbox collection and it set all of the arrays to [undefined], any ideas?

Comment: can you add  a sample document from the collection? looks like owner_id is missing in those document.

Comment: Just added an example document for you!

Comment: Ok actually, it appears that the script works fine, it just updates about 10 documents at a time before quitting. Do you have any ideas about making it stay alive until all documents from the query are updated?

Comment: I tried this script with the sample document, worked fine. needed to change the name of the collection in save call in foreach function.

Comment: Are you sure it fails after 10 document, maybe it's failing for some specific document giving error.

Comment: That's possible. I had to do some data cleaning. Any way about it, I really appreciate the help